# how to find combination from sublist of size n in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list

- triangle = ['0, 3, 2', '0, 3, 1', '0, 2, 3','1, 3, 0', '1, 3, 5']

I want to get an output of

```
0,2,3  #since 0,3,2 would be the same combination
0,3,1
1,3,5
```

I use the following code below

```
from itertools import combinations
for comb in combinations(triangle, 3):
    print comb
```

however my results are pairs  of 3 i.e

```
'0, 3, 2', '0, 3, 1', '0, 2, 3'
etc.
```

I have also tried changing the like

```
for comb in combinations(triangle, 3):
              to
for comb in combinations(triangle, 1):
```

however the combinations are not unique

Comment: just making sure: your `triangle` is supposed to be a list of comma separated strings of 3 numbers?

Comment: Can you explain the question better? So you want to find '0, 3, 2' because a combination of it exists in the list also?

Comment: do you care which combonation I choose if there's a duplictate? (why `'0,2,3'` and not `'0,3,2'`?)

Comment: @Adam.Er8 i meant to include the part where i sort the list from least to greatest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary with a frozenset as a key to effectively deduplicate and then take a list of its values, eg:

```
triangle = ['0, 3, 2', '0, 3, 1', '0, 2, 3','1, 3, 0', '1, 3, 5']
output = list({frozenset(el.split(', ')): el for el in triangle}.values())
```

Gives you:

```
['0, 2, 3', '1, 3, 0', '1, 3, 5']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of strings. You can do sth like:

```
triangle = ['0, 3, 2', '0, 3, 1', '0, 2, 3','1, 3, 0', '1, 3, 5']
list(map(', '.join, set(tuple(sorted(s.split(', '))) for s in triangle)))
# ['1, 3, 5', '1, 3, 0', '2, 3, 0']
```